# How to get multiple most commons values from array and add them to another?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[2 1 2 4 3 3 1]
```

I'm using this...

```
var query = array.GroupBy(item => item)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => g.Key)
    .First();
```

.. to get first most common value (in this case : 2)

What if I want to get multiple values (in this case: 2,3,1) ?

I need to add this values to another temporary array to check if this tempArray.Count > 1.

Comment: Why is 2 the most common value and not 3?

Comment: corrected, just little mistake, sorry

Comment: Well now my question is: why is 3 the most common value and not 2?!

Comment: 2 was correct according to the description: `first most common`

Comment: Does it really matter ?

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get all groups tied for the top count, you could do it like this:

```
var tmp = array
   .GroupBy(item => item)
   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
   .Select(g => new {
       Item = g.Key
   ,   Count = g.Count()
   }).ToList();
var res = tmp
    .TakeWhile(p => p.Count == tmp[0].Count)
    .Select(p => p.Item)
    .ToList();
```

Note that the check for `tmp` list count to be non-zero is unnecessary, because the only way the `TakeWhile` condition is executed is when there is at least a single item in the temporary list. In other words, when `tmp` is empty, the lambda condition `p => p.Count == tmp[0].Count` is never reached, and the out-of-range exception is never thrown.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach it (splitting out the code for clarity):

```
//Basic query
var query = array
    .GroupBy(i => i);

//Get the maximum count number
var maxCount = query
    .Max(i => i.Count());

//Get all the values that have a count of maxCount
var result = query
    .Where(i => i.Count() == maxCount)
    .Select(i => i.Key);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying you want the top 3 results:

```
var query = array.GroupBy(item => item)
  .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
  .Select(g => g.Key).Take(3);
```

Comment: It wasn't initially clear in the question that they wanted only the tied-top numbers returning.